# Porcentaje de ventas del mes actual

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Quiero sacar el porcentaje de las ventas del mes del año actual. Es decir sumo el total de las ventas del mes de cada mes y las divido entre el total de ventas del año.

```
SELECT
    *,
    sum(total_venta) as total_venta 
FROM compra 
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha_factura) /
    (SELECT
         sum(total_venta) * 100 as porcentaje
     FROM compra)
```

Pero no me está saliendo.

Comment: ¿Cual base de datos usas? Las etiquetas se contradicen. No puede ser MySQL y Oracle a la vez.

Answer (score 1):

Me encontré este ejemplo nada mas checa los nombres de tu tabla y columnas, modifica estos en la siguiente query.

applying OVER() to get summary total and percent on base.

```
SELECT   MONTH = MONTH(OrderDate), SUM(TotalDue) AS SalesByMonth, 
         100.0 * ((SUM(TotalDue)) / (SUM(SUM(TotalDue)) 
                                       OVER())) AS PctSalesByMonth 
FROM     AdventureWorks2008.Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
WHERE    YEAR(OrderDate) = 2003 
GROUP BY MONTH(OrderDate) 
ORDER BY MONTH;
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que tu consulta es en mysql, podés hacer la consulta haciendo la suma y el subquery directamente dentro del query principal. Podés usar el siguiente código:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    sum(total_venta) as total_venta, 
    sum(idTipoProducto)/(SELECT SUM(total_venta) FROM compra ) * 100 as porcentaje_venta 
FROM compra 
GROUP BY MONTH(fecha_factura);
```